# Navigating to SharePoint using teamslogon.aspx doesn't work Teams mobile

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I want to navigate SharePoint in Teams tab app by clicking button as below, but it doesn't work properly **only** in MS Teams Mobile app(works with desktop), it shows the loading screen.

```
var url= https://${DOMAIN_URL}/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?spfx=true&dest=/${SITE_URL};
window.location.replace( url );
```

is there any reason for that ?

[image]

manifest similar to this

```
 "staticTabs": [
         {
             "entityId": "16f1325347cb",
             "name": "Portals7",
             "contentUrl": "https://my-site-url.io/Tab?loginHint={loginHint}&userObjectId={userObjectId}&userPrincipalName={userPrincipalName}&tenantId={tid}&locale={locale}&theme={theme}&userPrincipalName={userPrincipalName}",
    
             "websiteUrl": "https://my-site-url.io/Tab",
             
             "scopes": ["personal"],
             "supportedPlatform" : ["desktop"]
         }
     ],
   "permissions": [
     "identity",
     "messageTeamMembers"
   ],
   "validDomains": [
   "my-site-url.io",
      
     "*.login.microsoftonline.com",
     "*.sharepoint.com",
     "*.sharepoint-df.com",
     "spoppe-a.akamaihd.net",
     "spoprod-a.akamaihd.net",
     "resourceseng.blob.core.windows.net",
     "msft.spoppe.com"
   ],
   "webApplicationInfo": {
     "id": "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
     "resource": "https://{teamSiteDomain}"
   }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried to open the developer tools console to see if you get any error or warning. I mean, you can do it on mobile, too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a manifest error, we need to provide all supported platforms.

"supportedPlatform": [ "desktop","mobile","teamsMeetingDevices" ]

Comment: it is still giving same loading screen in mobile

Comment: Could you please share the console log errors if you are getting any?